# How to remove 3 or more the same character

Tags: ruby

During my lessons of Ruby I came across of this exercise. I'm trying to remove 3 or more the same charactes in a row. Test Cases Input: abbbaaccada Output: ccada Input: bbccdddcb Output: (Empty string)

So far I have solution which doesn't return expected results:

```
def playground("abbbaaccada")
  count = string.length
  string.chars.each_with_index.map { |v, i| (v * (count - i)).capitalize }.join('')
end

output gives me
==> AaaaaaaaaaaBbbbbbbbbbBbbbbbbbbBbbbbbbbAaaaaaaAaaaaaCccccCcccAaaDdA
instead of
==> ccada
```

Could you please advise?

Edit:
Forgot to add that regexp isn't allowed

Comment: You said you want `"abbbaaccada"` to return `""ccada"`. That suggests you want to remove runs of three or more, then remove runs of three or more from what is left, and continue to do that until no further removals of runs of three or more can be done. You need to say that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def recursively_remove_runs_of_3_or_more(str)
  arr = str.chars
  loop do
    a = arr.slice_when { |a,b| a.downcase != b.downcase }.to_a
    b = a.reject! { |e| e.size > 2 }
    arr = a.flatten
    break arr.join if b.nil?
  end
end

recursively_remove_runs_of_3_or_more "abbbaaccada"
  #=> "ccada"
```

This uses [Enumerable#slice_when](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_when) (new in MRI v2.2). Note that [Array#reject!](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-reject-21) returns `nil` when no changes are made.

You could alternatively use [Enumerable#chunk_while](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk_while) (new in MRI v2.3). Simply replace:

```
    a = arr.slice_when { |a,b| a.downcase != b.downcase }.to_a
```

with:

```
    a = arr.chunk_while { |a,b| a.downcase == b.downcase }.to_a
```

`chunk_while` and `slice_when` are yin and yang.

If a regular expression could be used and case where not an issue, you could write:

```
str = "abbbaaccada"
s = str.dup
loop { break(s) if s.gsub!(/(.)\1{2,}/, '').nil? }
  #=> "ccada"
```

Comment: Well this not gives us expected solution. The result for string `abbbaaccada` is `aabbbadb` instead of `ccada` . unfortunately the regexp is not allowed for this solutions.

Comment: wichru, I changed my answer to reflect my current understanding of the question and to avoid using a regex.

Answer (score 1):

There are two challenges here:

- Match and remove any run of thee or more characters in a row
- Recurse to test again in case the previous step created a new run of three

Here's one way to do it:

```
THREE_OR_MORE = /(.)\1{2,}/
def three_is_too_many(str)
  if str.match? THREE_OR_MORE
    str = three_is_too_many(str.gsub(THREE_OR_MORE, ''))
  end
  str
end
```

The regexp finds any character ('.'), followed by itself ('\1'), two or more times ('{2,}').

Then the routine either a) removes three or more and tests again or b) returns the string.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation unfortunately regexp is not allowed for this solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a potential solution.  The following method searches for any subsequence of an array with repeats, and returns the range of the repeated values if there are three or more of them.

```
def find_3_or_more(ary)
  ary.each_index do |i|
    j = i + 1
    while j < ary.length && ary[i] == ary[j]
      j += 1
    end
    return (i...j) if j - i > 2
  end
  nil
end
```

This portion breaks the target string into an array of chars, and repeatedly slices out the characters in ranges identified as repeats until there are none, as indicated by a `nil` range.

```
def delete_3_or_more(str)
  ary = str.chars
  while r = find_3_or_more(ary)
    ary.slice!(r)
  end
  return ary.join
end
```

It seems to do the job for your test cases.

Answer (score 0):

(I wanted to comment, but it doesn't allow me to do that yet.)
Assuming that you are trying to learn, I chose to only give you some tips while avoiding a solution.

There might be shorter ways of doing this using regex or/and some String methods. However, you said you can not use regex.

My tip is, try to solve it only using **the sections you have covered so far**. It may not necessarily be the most elegant solution, but you can revise it as you progress. As others suggested, recursion might be a good option. But, if you are not familiar with that yet, you can try slicing the string and merging the parts you need. This can be combined with an endless loop to check the new string satisfies your condition: but think about **when you need to break out of the loop**.

Also, in your code:

> `v * (count - i)`

[String#*](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-2A) actually gives you `count - i` copies of `v`, concatenated together.